# What is the SYSTEM group in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security

I want to disallow access to a drive in Windows 7, to all the users except myself (admin). So I have deleted all the users and groups in the drive's Security dialog but I am not sure whether I should also delete the "SYSTEM" group or not. If I delete it, does it mean that Windows won't have access to this drive anymore?

In general, does anybody know what this group is for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably leave it be. As I understand it, SYSTEM is used by many services etc. Actual users cannot put themselves into the SYSTEM group without being an administrator (and even then, I think you've got to do it with some strange method..).

Answer (score 7):

The `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` account is used by most Windows services (via [`LocalSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Removing it won't prevent the Windows kernel from accessing the drive, but it might break *some* services that do it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is Microsoft's explanation of [how the system account is used](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/120929). It says

> The system account is used by the operating system and by services that run under Windows.